# General term of $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)...$?

Tags: combinatorics, closed-form, integer-partitions

Is there a closed for the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\cdots$? If not, then what is the closest to a closed form that anyone has found? (An infinite series that approximates it perhaps? Or maybe something of the type "the coefficient of $x^n$ is the closest integer to **____**" where the blank is filled by a complicated looking expression? Etc.)

Note: I already know that that the coefficient of $x^n$ can be interpreted as the number of ways to write $n$ as the sum of zero or one $1$'s, zero or one $2$'s, zero or one $3$'s, etc., but I haven't been able to prove anything interesting from this view point.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts = number of partitions of $n$ into odd parts.  This is a very well-studied sequence.  See [OEIS sequence A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009), in particular the Formula section and the References and Links.

Comment: see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function

Comment: If you want to calculate these without calculating coeffs of the gf directly, I think the best formula is the recursive one in the OEIS: a(n)=(1/n)*Sum_{k=1..n} b(k)*a(n-k), with a(0)=1 and b(n)= A000593(n) = sum of odd divisors of n.